# Can I use jwt to store a user's shopping cart items until checkout?

Tags: jwt, mean-stack

I'm using the MEAN stack on my site, where users can add events with player information (2-4/event) to the cart.  Sometimes they purchase multiple events.  I'd like this information to be safe from user manipulation (changing info before checking out if they use console) and able to be stored for a short time in case they are interrupted during checkout.

Would I be able to add their cart items to their JWT, and then remove it once they checkout and the data is stored in the database or is there a better option?  I saw options for local-storage or session-storage but am not sure what the best option is.

Comment: this is a good question. i would love to hear other people's opinion on this...

Comment: Me too, I see the value of being able to encrypt the data in the jwt as brilliant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory there is no limit max size of JWT, but in practice, it is used to authenticate the user so supposedly the smaller the better. I think it's totally possible strategy. The advantage of using jwt would be that it doesn't have to hit the db. On the other hand, a lookup like this (normally) should be be trivial. You also should be careful that you don't leak any secrets into the jwt since it is possible to view the contents.

Comment: Thank you!  I like the idea of using the web tokens rather than just local storage alone because it's storing encrypted data and I don't want people to be able to mess with details like WHERE the event is held or how much they pay.  I just wasn't sure it could be done.

Comment: there is also the jwe it might help

Comment: I've never heard of that before!  jwe and jwt seem so similar at first glance.

Comment: jwe (json web encryption) is interesting it is a standard for encryption. i'm not super familiar with it, but because the payload inside jwt can be decoded by anyone, the jwe was also a standard created to handle this. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=json+web+encryption

Comment: I thought the jwt needed the secret key in order to be decoded?

Comment: i thought so too, but you have to be careful the stuff you put in there. actually if it's just items on a cart you might just get away with not encrypting it. but if you want encryption it might be better to use jwe. you can test your jwt here https://jwt.io/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142029/discussion-between-rbtlong-and-user3561890).

Comment: I ended up using 'ngStorage' instead of jwt.  I may end up using crypto-js to further secure the information further.

Comment: sounds like that also a great choice